# ADX Kusto find most recent rows for multiple id tuples

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Given I have Devices with an ID and each Device has different telemetry aspects which are stored to an ADX table. Each of these aspects is identified by a `TelemetryId`. The `DeviceId` is unique, but the `TelemetryId` is not. This Device-Telemery tuples are stored as individual rows in ADX. So the table looks like:

```
|DeviceId|TelemetryId|Value|TimeStamp|
|--------|-----------|-----|----------------------------|
|1       | 1         | 10  | 2022-06-15 08:50:42.016496 |
|1       | 2         | 20  | 2022-06-15 08:50:41.072425 |
|1       | 3         | 30  | 2022-06-15 08:50:40.199198 |
|2       | 1         | 11  | 2022-06-15 08:50:39.366868 |
|2       | 2         | 22  | 2022-06-15 08:50:38.536320 |
|2       | 3         | 33  | 2022-06-15 08:50:37.602781 |
|2       | 4         | 44  | 2022-06-15 08:50:36.702367 |
|2       | 5         | 55  | 2022-06-15 08:50:35.677494 |
|1       | 1         | 12  | 2022-06-15 08:50:34.750020 |
|1       | 2         | 22  | 2022-06-15 08:50:33.752211 |
```

Now I need the information about the most recent data containing all Telementry data for a specific `DeviceId`. From the query consumer perspective, I know which `DeviceId` exist in the system and which `TelemetryId` are assigned to each `DeviceId`. So I can use this information to build the query.

So for example, if I would query for `DeviceId == 1` I would expect this result:

```
|DeviceId|TelemetryId|Value|TimeStamp|
|--------|-----------|-----|----------------------------|
|1       | 1         | 10  | 2022-06-15 08:50:42.016496 |
|1       | 2         | 20  | 2022-06-15 08:50:41.072425 |
|1       | 3         | 30  | 2022-06-15 08:50:40.199198 |
```

But I’m not sure if this can be achieved with a single Kusto Query? (I know how to do it with multiple ADX queries (one query for each Device-Telemetry tuple) but I am wondering if it is possible to get it done with one Query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

For performance reasons, you should consider narrowing the dataset by TimeStamp before applying the aggregation, E.g. querying only the last week/day/hour, depends on your data ingestion behaviour.

```
datatable (DeviceId:int, TelemetryId:int, Value:int, TimeStamp:datetime)
[
     1 ,1 ,10 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:42.016496"
    ,1 ,2 ,20 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:41.072425"
    ,1 ,3 ,30 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:40.199198"
    ,2 ,1 ,11 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:39.366868"
    ,2 ,2 ,22 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:38.536320"
    ,2 ,3 ,33 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:37.602781"
    ,2 ,4 ,44 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:36.702367"
    ,2 ,5 ,55 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:35.677494"
    ,1 ,1 ,12 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:34.750020"
    ,1 ,2 ,22 ,"2022-06-15 08:50:33.752211"
]
| summarize arg_max(TimeStamp, *) by DeviceId, TelemetryId
```

| DeviceId | TelemetryId | TimeStamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 2022-06-15T08:50:35.677494Z | 55 |
| 2 | 4 | 2022-06-15T08:50:36.702367Z | 44 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-06-15T08:50:37.602781Z | 33 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-06-15T08:50:38.53632Z | 22 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-06-15T08:50:39.366868Z | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-06-15T08:50:40.199198Z | 30 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-06-15T08:50:41.072425Z | 20 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-06-15T08:50:42.016496Z | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA33SwUrEMBAG4Huh7xD2tCvdMJkkk6ZnL54VLyKStUEKjUjNiis%20vAlrNUKw/S9pv8OfZEYX03uYPdte%20rfp0V%20Nw/QcO3bjZx98XE7rh1s3H/33vyn46%20jCyzC66GNa7drmrm1YfgTrcoB1GwTEPdBeaAb9oGFQyEGQsrQ54ywxpY4FB4MKdYFlSh0DF9YK268YzzVEDUvLJVFPJc7BKu65liQRCpxryCo2nABNLwqsUlQVEzeAkkyBdYquYs3JGGVVcRo59c6KGw3w21n8t0GZMKLIne/b5pO9HkNwy/ThmVueHoJ73/5ceMcuduxwYuus/JmTL%20Ju7zdMAgAA)