# To carry forward the update to next hour if not received using KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

```
  Time                Product   Value
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B1        25
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B2        46
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B3        18

2022-06-20T02:00:00Z   B1        26
2022-06-20T02:00:00Z   B2        40
```

How can i carry forward B3 to 2022-06-20T02:00:00Z if i have not received any updates for B3 at 2022-06-20T02:00:00Z

Required output:

```
  Time                Product   Value
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B1        25
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B2        46
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B3        18

2022-06-20T02:00:00Z   B1        26
2022-06-20T02:00:00Z   B2        40
2022-06-20T01:00:00Z   B3        18
```

Comment: The request is not clear.  How many records do you want to return in this scenario, 3 or 6?  What's going to happen on the next hour, assuming once again you get data only for B1 & B2, but not for B3?

Comment: In the above case i have not received any update for B3 product at 2 AM, so i have to carry forward the last record i.e B3 from 1 AM  to 2AM with datetime as 2022-06-20T02:00:00Z

Comment: This part is clear. I still need answers to my questions

Comment: I want to return 3 records. At 2AM, B1,B2 and B3 should be returned if no updates at 3 AM, all the 3 records from 2Am should be returned with datetime as 2022-06-20T03:00:00Z  and so on..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADX Kusto find most recent rows for multiple id tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627277/adx-kusto-find-most-recent-rows-for-multiple-id-tuples)